# Okay so, $x^2$ is square, $x^3$ is cube, $x^4$ is m-cube?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, volume

I'm trying to get some intuition, I think it almost makes sense, since you can think of the area of a square is length multiplied by height. The volume of a cube is length multiplied by height, multiplied by depth. I don't understand how to find the volume of the hypercube. What's the correct intuition?

Comment: You mean the volume of the cube and the hyper-volume of the hypercube.

Comment: Yes, I do think I mean hyper-volume.

Comment: The hyper-volume of a hypercube is length multiplied by height, multiplied by depth multiplied by the fourth dimension witch is not exist in 3D world.

Comment: So, since this is a hypercube, the lengths of all the sides are the same? The length of the side of the hypercube in the fourth dimension is equal to the length of one of the sides in one of the typical 3 dimensions?

Comment: What's $n$, the length of one edge of the hypercube?  I'd prefer to call that $x$, or something, because $n$ is often used for integer values.  For a hypercube, the lengths of all the edges are the same.  Instead of "hypercube", we could also use the term $m$-cube for a hypercube in $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: Edited, thanks!

Comment: The area of a cube *is not* its height times length times depth.

Comment: Oh, right. I meant volume. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you would call the "volume" of a cube is the "hyper-volume" of a "hypercube".  And regular volume of a hypercube is like surface area on a regular cube.  To put these concepts into equations:

(by squares, I mean rectangles.  by cubes, I mean rectangular prisms.  etc.)

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf{Hyper\ V} & =2^0\left(\underbrace{l_1[\times(l_2\times[l_3\times(l_4)])]}_{1\times2\times3\times4}\right) \\
\mathsf{Volume} & =2^1\left(\underbrace{l_1\times[l_2\times(l_3+l_4)]}_{1\times2\times(3+4)}+\underbrace{l_2\times[l_3\times(l_4)]}_{2\times3\times4}\right) \\
\mathsf{Area} & =2^2\left(\underbrace{l_1\times(l_2+l_3+l_4)}_{1\times(2+3+4)}+\underbrace{l_2\times(l_3+l_4)}_{2\times(3+4)}+\underbrace{l_3\times(l_4)}_{3\times4}\right) \\
\mathsf{Length/Edge?} & =2^3\left(\underbrace{l_1+l_2+l_3+l_4}_{1+2+3+4}\right)
\end{align}$$

See if you can spot the pattern and construct it for regular cubes and squares.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that
"square" and "cube" are used
is their source in
Euclidean geometry
from the corresponding
geometrical figures.

Since the Greeks
could not visualize
higher dimensions
(I can not either),
no name was given to
higher powers.

I just use
"fourth power",
"fifth power",
and, in general,
"n-th power".